# Radio buttons group is not working in data list

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am bound to use asp radio button in datalist it selects all the radio buttons when clicked group name property not seems to be working inside datalist. So far I have this javascript function which deselect all the radio buttons on page and than select the clicked radio button. But when this script executes at first it selects the last radio button in the datalist second time when radio button clicked from datalist it selects the correct radio button and de select all others. it also de select other radio buttons outside the datalist. I want to de select the radio buttons only inside datalist. And why first time it is selects the last radio button inside datalist. Any help will be much appriciated.

```
                            function fnrad(rbtn) {
                            var radioList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

                            for (var i = 0; i < radioList.length; i++) {

                                if (radioList[i].type == "radio") {
                                    radioList[i].name = 'a';
                                    radioList[i].setAttribute("Checked", "");

                                }
                            }

                            rbtn.setAttribute("Checked", "checked");
                        }
```

Datalist Markup

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dtImages" RepeatColumns="5" OnItemDataBound="dtImages_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="height: 150px; vertical-align: middle;">
                                        <img src='<%#"../CreateThumbnail.aspx?image=images/searchbox/" + BindImage(Container.DataItem.ToString()) + "&size=200" %>' />

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" onclick='fnrad(this);' GroupName="a" ID="rd" Text=<%# BindImage(Container.DataItem.ToString()) %> />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are selecting all input element of form, thats why it select outer radio also.

Change JS function as below, selector changed to select those elements whose id start with dtImages_rd  :

```
function fnrad(rbtn) {
     var radioList = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="dtImages_rd"]');
     for (var i = 0; i < radioList.length; i++) {
       if (radioList[i].type == "radio") {
            radioList[i].name = 'a';
            radioList[i].removeAttribute("Checked");
          }
       }
       rbtn.setAttribute("Checked", "checked");
 }
```